# customize "copy of" prefix when creating copies of files and folders in windows

Tags: windows

I would like to customize the 'copy of' that windows automatically prefixes to files/folders that you make a copy of.. to something like filename_2

Any ideas?

Comment: What Windows version are you exactly using? I get `_2` my default on Windows 7...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this were hard-coded into XP.